# how to select multiple checkbox validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, function

Here is my Form. I need validation in JavaScript.
At least one checkbox selected in validation.
I hop you all are understand what I need.
please give me solution for that.
If any query then feel free ask.

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="studentregistration" onsubmit="return(validate());">

        <table cellpadding="3" width="100%" align="center" cellspacing="3">
            <tr>
                <td>Hobby</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="Chess" id="hobby">Chess
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="Music" id="hobby">Music<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="Cricket" id="hobby">Cricket
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby" value="Reading" id="hobby">Reading
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit Form" value="Submit Form" id="submitform">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

</form>
```

Comment: i need at least one select in selectbox

Comment: The way you are using the submit the form, it does not matter if you will check the check boxes or not. You can only submit the form after verification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another easy answer

```
var test = document.getElementsByName("hobby[]");
if(test[0].checked==false && test[1].checked==false && test[2].checked==false && test[3].checked==false)
{
    alert("Please Check");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to validate that at least one checkbox is checked, then this should work for you using jQuery:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In "pure" js, you could remove the `onsubmit` attribute and do this instead:

```
document.querySelector('form[name="studentregistration"]').onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var cbx = document.querySelectorAll('form[name="studentregistration"] input[name="hobby"]:checked');
    if(cbx.length > 0) {
        // at least one checked - do something
    }
    else {
        // none checked
    }
}
```

[See a live demo!](http://jsbin.com/lirexuqibo/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 1):

Complete solution.

In order to submit the form after validation you must use:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

```js
document.getElementById("submitform").addEventListener("click",submit_form);
function submit_form(e){
var ob = "";
var chess = document.getElementById("hobby1").checked;
var music = document.getElementById("hobby2").checked;
var cricket = document.getElementById("hobby3").checked;
var reading  = document.getElementById("hobby4").checked;
if(chess == true){
ob += "hobby: chess selected!\n";
}
if(music == true){
ob += "hobby: music selected!\n";
}
if(cricket == true){
ob += "hobby: cricket selected!\n";
}
if(reading == true){
ob += "hobby: reading selected!\n";
}
if(ob==""){
alert("No hobbys selected");
}
else{
alert(ob);
//document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
//for testing purposes
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
  
}
```

```html
<form id = "myForm" action="#" method="post" name="studentregistration">

        <table cellpadding="3" width="100%" align="center" cellspacing="3">
            <tr>
                <td>Hobby</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby"  id="hobby1">Chess
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby"  id="hobby2">Music<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby"  id="hobby3">Cricket
                    <input type="checkbox" name="hobby"  id="hobby4">Reading
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
<input type="button" name="Submit Form" value="Submit Form" id="submitform">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("#hobby").is(':checked')){
alert("checkbox checked");
}
else{
alert("Please select at least one checkbox");
}
```